# WWW-Authenticate is not being sent with HTML login form of Keycloak

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, kerberos, spnego, www-authenticate

As per [this doc](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/docs/documentation/server_admin/topics/authentication/kerberos.adoc) and as its item 4 says:

> renders the HTML login screen with status 401 and HTTP header WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate.

In the meantime, I don't see anything like this in the response of my keycloak (WWW-Authenticate header is not present).

User federation was set up along with krb5.conf and all things on AD side (SPN, keytab, correct principal, etc).
Moreover, if I set option "Use Kerberos for password" I can see in debug logs it really uses Kerberos for password check and perform it successfully. I mean I can login with my account name and password provided manually.

It makes me think that something wrong in keycloak settings rather than in AD or keytab, but I really can't get where the problem is and how to get users to login transparantly. May I miss something significant?

Additionally, after redirect to keycloak login form, I can find an exception in logs:

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.federation.kerberos.impl.SPNEGOAuthenticator] (executor-thread-117) SPNEGO login failed: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
```

I use Chrome, and have done all necessary things to add keycloak's hostname to auth-server-whitelist.

```
Keycloak's URL: https://auth.company.com
AD domain: DOMAIN.LOCAL
Server principal: HTTP/auth.company.com@DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

In the TRACE output I found some interesting lines:

```
2023-07-31 09:57:21,366 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (executor-thread-2) invoke authenticator.authenticate: auth-spnego
2023-07-31 09:57:21,366 TRACE [org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.SpnegoAuthenticator] (executor-thread-2) Sending back WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

But why the WWW-Authenticate actually keeps not showing up in headers of the /realms/{my realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth page?

Please help.

Comment: Are there any reverse proxies in front of Keycloak?

Comment: Thanks for your attention, there is no any reverse proxy.

Comment: Check that NTLM as fallback protocol is not used on client side